# Deep Linking in Foundation For Apps

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am new to Foundation for Apps and am trying to get deep linking to work with the zf-tabs directive. Basically, I have a view with tabs and I am trying to use $state.go in my controller to navigate to the view and activate a particular tab. I have gotten the URL to write correctly with the hash but the tab doesn't activate. I see a lot of discussion on how to do this in the other foundation frameworks but there is zero info on this for Foundation For Apps.

Comment: Can you please add it to `jsfiddle` what you have done so far! So that I can look into the exact issue what you are trying?

Comment: I could mock something up I guess. It's not really practical to do a fiddle for me. I have lots of controllers and partials. Maybe if I just ask the question. How can a get Foundation for Apps to activate a tab that I create using the zf-tabs directive from code in a controller?